# KML support in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, kml, plugins

I know that GeoJSON is supported in Leaflet but how about KML? Is there any plugin for reading KML data in Leaflet?

Comment: Web search with leaflet+kml+plugin seems to give results.

Comment: It is possible with omnivore.kml here https://github.com/mapbox/leaflet-omnivore

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, [there is a plugin for that](http://leafletjs.com/plugins.html#overlay-data-formats).